# indexing vertices in polyhedron_3 class

Tags: c++, 3d, mesh, cgal, vertices

I am new to CGAL. I know we can use vertex iterator to iterate all vertices in a polyhedron object. But how can I randomly sample a vertex in a given polyhedron and do something around it.

And does CGAL provide any way to index the 3D vertices? Like we use [x,y](integers) to index pixels in a image.

Comment: If you use the class [Surface_mesh](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/index.html) instead, you'll be able to access vertices using indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case (non-regular polyhedra), the solution would necessarily be 1D. The simplest solution is: collect alll the vertices is a list/vector/set and call that list "the indexing map of my polyhedron"

Other, more sophisticated solution are possible, but I really doubt they can bring any advantages. E.g:

1. express your polyhedron as a graph {vertices, edges}
2. denote one vertex as the starting node
3. apply any transversal algo (depth or breadth) to the graph and index the vertices in the order of their appearance.

For regular polyhedra, more advanced numbering scheme exists, but they aren't going to be trivial (except for the cube, of course). Take [this Q/A on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151597/conventional-ordering-of-faces-of-regular-polyhedron) as a starting point